# Free alternative to Roboform for filling forms and saving passwords?

Tags: forms, password-manager

I seek free software for Windows 10 OS, with the following features for IE and Chrome and Firefox:

1. automatically completing forms and fields;
2. saving passwords.

I can't use Roboform anymore, as it's expensive. What alternatives are there?

Comment: As password stores an form-filler are usually separate applications, you might wish to ask separate questions to keep things clear ;)

Answer (score 3):

for security reasons i would strongly advise against web-based services to store your secret passwords!
instead i would highly recommend a local installed open source software and just sync your encrypted passwords across your devices via any sync-service...

---

as specific software i can recommend [KeePassXC](https://keepassxc.org/) (a fork of KeePassX) with several good [features](https://keepassxc.org/project/):

- it is free as in beer and speech
- available cross-platform for Windows, MacOS and Linux
- auto-type (including TOTP) on all supported platforms
- import-function
- password- & passphrase-generator (with strength-meter)
- for the database-files it uses the KDBX-format from [KeePass](http://keepass.info/)

With its countless [ports](http://keepass.info/download.html) (even for Android, iOS, Windows Mobile, BlackBerry, etc.) you are platform independent and don't have to hand over your passwords to a cloud service.

Comment: Good advice concerning passwords (I'd never ever store those with some "cloud service"). But what about "form filling"? To my knowledge, KeePass (in whichever flavor) doesn't feature that.

Comment: @Izzy well... you can a kind of work around it with [Custom Entries for Autotype](https://github.com/keepassxreboot/keepassxc/wiki/Autotype-Custom-Sequence#custom-entry-attributes) and setup two or more window-titles (with corresponding sequences) for autotype. - for sure you have to set this up for every form, but i'm not sure if this is also necessary with other form-fillers.

Comment: OK, so OP might better ask a separate question for that. +1 here meanwhile ;)

Answer (score 2):

I know you might be hesitant to sync your passwords and form fills with a cloud service, but if it helps you feel better if the service is open-source and constantly being updated, I would check out Bitwarden. It's free unless you want a little storage space for important files along with its other capabilities, and if you decide you want that, it's only $10/year. You can learn more at http://bitwarden.com/. Also, LastPass (http://lastpass.com/) has a really good free plan. That's what I use since Bitwarden didn't have some of the cool features LastPass has.

Answer (score 1):

[Enpass](https://www.enpass.io/) is free for all desktop OS though its mobile (Android/iOS) versions are freemium.